# Related to multiple tags

Tags: wireless, digital-communications, rfid, tag

I am trying to find out the following points related to multiple tags.

1. Whether multiple tags can have same information in them or they will always have different information.
2. Real life example of multiple tags in RFID.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What tags, what technology? Generally tags will have a unique number so the data area can be the same, but individual tags can be resolved.

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply....Its related to RFID tags...I agree with you that every tag will have unique number, but can they transmit same information ?

Comment: What tags, what technology?

Comment: Tags in RFID technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tags can be cloned, so yes.

Multiple tags, like my access tag and my mastercard. sometimes reader sees the wrong one and then I hold my wallet the other way.

Comment: Thank you sir...